# Javascript multidimensional array returns first value and then fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg, multidimensional-array

I am couting all svg-Elements from my html document in the var anzahl_der_SVGs. that works fine and it returns me 3 as it should. now i want to make a multidimensional array where i am going to store serveral svg-Element information. the structure is

[0][0] -> html code of svg

[0][1] -> id of a parent container

the javascript code is:

```
function getSVG(){

    var anzahl_der_SVGs = $('svg').size();
    alert(anzahl_der_SVGs);

    var svgArray    = new Array(anzahl_der_SVGs);
        svgArray[0] = new Array(2);

        $('svg').each(function( index ) {
            id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
            var speichern = "widgetID" +id;
            svgArray[index][0] = $(this).html();
            svgArray[index][1] = speichern;
            alert(svgArray[index][0]);
            alert(svgArray[index][1]);
            $(this).attr("id", speichern);
        });
}
```

The alerts from the first iteration work fine and it shows me the svg html and the widget ID. in the next iteration it stops and gives me console output " TypeError: svgArray[index] is undefined " thx for any help :) best regards from germany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. What you've done is define a nested array for the first index of `svgArray`. What you need to do is define one for each member.

You can do that in the `.each()` loop.

```
$('svg').each(function( index ) {
    if (!svgArray[index]) {
        svgArray[index] = new Array(2)
    }
```

Comment: Your remark is misleading.  Javascript certainly can have multidimensional arrays; the OP just didn't create it right.

Comment: @Malvolio: He's referring to actual multidimensional arrays. What JavaScript has isn't anything like that. It's just nested members that also happen to be arrays with a length equal to each other. There's no automation or enforcement of the rectangular structure.

Comment: You killed my father.  Prepare to die.

Comment: @Malvolio: Yeah, sorry about that. Turned out it was all just a big misunderstanding. I thought he ate my lunch, but then after I remembered that I didn't bring a lunch that day. Awkward...

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array of object would be much simpler :

```
var svgArray = [];
var cpt = 0;
$('svg').each(function( index ) {
        id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr("id");
        var speichern = "widgetID" +id;
        svgArray.push({html: $(this).html(), id : speichern});        
        alert(svgArray[cpt].html);
        alert(svgArray[cpt].id);
        $(this).attr("id", speichern);
        cpt++;
    });
```